# ios {app name}would like access your facebook account ask every time

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am developing an app that uses facebook authorization.

Authorize app like this

```
 FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
    // Set the active session
    [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
    // Open the session
    [session openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent
            completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                FBSessionState state,
                                NSError *error) {
                if (completion ) {
                    completion(error == nil);
                }

                [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
            }];
```

Then athe app will show a message like **{appname} would like to access your facebook account**.

On logout I am clearing caches and tokens. Next time login the app directly access fb account without any confirmation. If I remove authorization of app from fb settings(in browser) and remove app from device, The app will ask for confirmation.

Can I do like the app asks **{appname} would like to access your facebook account** confirmation every time ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's impossible, actually in the app, to "take away the app from the user's acceptable apps" (i.e., as you can on do, in a web browser on the Facebook page in the settings of your account)

Answer (score 2):

One time authorization is enough. Once the the user the allow access to your app then there is no point to ask again and again. If the current user logout and a different user login, facebook will ask for confirmation(seen this in web view/safari login flow) if he is not authorized.